# SVN Ant Update example

Tags: svn, ant

I'm quite new in Ant and i want to make an SVN Update operation.
I add the jar files into the ant/lib folder, also i add the typedef property in my build.xml file.

```
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpath="ant/lib/svnant.jar;ant/lib/svnClientAdapter.jar;ant/lib/svnkit.jar;ant/lib/svnjavahl.jar" />
```

But now I need some code example for making update from repository at one folder (let's say the folder name is test)
I look over internet but a few examples are provided with this svn ant call.

I've tried something like this

```
<target name="svn-update">
    <svn username="test" password="*****">
        <update revision="HEAD" dir="com.project.blackbox.eclipse" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

Comment: Hi, where are the latest versions of these files? I keep on getting the follwing error : Reference svnant.classpath not found with the follwing :  <path id="path.svnant">
        <pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnant.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnkit.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${SVN.ANT.LIB}/svnjavahl.jar"/>
          <!-- ... -->
    </path>
  <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="path.svnant" />

Comment: @tinti if its working now for  you can you share the complete code and where can I get the jar files to paste into the ant/lib folder. I am trying to accomplish the very same thing but am not able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the typedefs right.

What you are trying to do is update to a directory which wasn't checked out by SVN.  This means that your likely have the wrong directory in your "dir" attribute.

If your "dir" attribute points to the project's root directory, odds are it is wrong.  You likely checked out to a "src" folder under the project's root directory.

Look in the Project's root directory (typically it is under the Workspace "root" directory, in a directory with the same name as the project).  Look for any subdirectories that contain a ".svn" hidden directory.  Odds are you only checked out from one repository, so if that's true then the first one you find will likely be the directory you meant to include in the "dir" directive.

If you have multiple directories to select from, at the command line do a "svn info ." for each candidate directory and you will soon be able to sort them out.

Comment: In my Workspace i have a .svn folder. The error i receive is       [svn] svn: Cannot read from 'c:\Users\test\projects\Workspace\com.project.blackbox.eclipse\.svn\format' I cannot understand what format folder/file is involved because this file does not exist in my .svn folder

Comment: All the files inside the ".svn" folder are svn's internal tracking and configuration storage.  If you can't read a file, it's either simple file permissions, or your command line client is a different version than your eclipse embedded client and they can't read each other's files.

Comment: I am having an error  `Problem: failed to create task or type svn` , what should I do.?

Comment: Odds are you have just copied in the typedef, but you also need to make sure the files you refer to in the typedef exist on disk at the same locations they are in your typedef.  If they do not, modify the typedef to match the files, or find / move the files to match the typedef.  The typedef tells ant where to find the extensions to load.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution mate:

### Requirement:

```
tortisesvn version - 1.7
subversuin version - 1.7
Ant version - 1.8 

Make sure you checkout with with new version of tortisesvn client. 

<!-- Execute svn update command -->
<target name="fetch-update-code" description="Fetches update code from base/current working repository" >
    <exec executable="svn" dir="D:/opt/trunk" spawn="false">
        <arg value="update" />
        <arg value="--username=${svn.username}" />
        <arg value="--password=${svn.password}" />
    </exec>
</target>


 Hope this helps:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you use path delimiters in the dir attribute:

```
<svn username="test" password="*****">
    <update revision="HEAD" dir="${basedir}/com.project.blackbox.eclipse" />
</svn>
```

There should be nothing special with the update command. You just have to make sure that you are using the correct directory and it have to be a svn working copy.

Comment: the name of the file is com.project.blackbox.eclipse

Comment: i got this error       [svn] svn: 'c:\Users\test\projects\Workspace\com.project.blackbox.eclipse' is not a working copy

Comment: You have to use the name of the folder your project is saved in - not the package name.

Comment: the next error line is [svn] svn: 'c:\Users\test\projects\Workspace\com.project.blackbox.eclipse' is not a working copy

Comment: @tinti: I guess this is not the correct path to your file? You have to prepend the filename with a base directory.