# "attribute 'file' is not a file" error using SvnAnt <update>

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

What wrong with my update?

```
<svn refid="svn.settings" logFile="D:\Copyof\anttt\R\log1.log">
    <checkout url="${svn.url}" destpath="D:\Copyof\anttt\R\OXS" revision="HEAD" depth="empty" />
    <update file="D:/Copyof/anttt/R/OXS/111.sql" dir="D:/Copyof/anttt/R/OXS" recurse="false"/>
</svn>
```

I got an error:

> The attribute 'file' is not a file

If I change my update like this:

```
<update file="${svn.url}/111.sql" recurse= "false"/>
```

I get an error that the path is wrong. I got the pathbuild from nowhere.

```
D:/javaproject/build/https://.....
```

Comment: Please see if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326731/svn-ant-update-example

Comment: @Rao i check it before and it wasent not usefull , he didnt specify what should be add in the `file` attribute , also i want to know should the file to be update from repisotery exists in the folder ? maybe thats my mistake